# Chartjs, How to edit data option after creating a chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Sorry if this is a trivial question. The issue I am having is I want to use the same data for multiple charts but some of the options are slightly different for each chart. The data is:

```
    var data = {
      labels: freq,
      datasets: [{
        borderWidth:1,
        label: "ADC Vizualization",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointRadius: 1,
        data: mag
     }]
    };
```

So then lets say I want to use this data but have the pointRadius be 5 instead for this specific chart.I know I can do this to set the data.

```
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(mycanvas,{
  data:data
})
```

but I want to be able to set the pointRadius to 5 instead of 1. Basically I want to say something like this:

```
var myLineChart = Chart.line(mycanvas,{
  data:data,
  data.datasets.pointRadius: 5
})
```

Would this be possible to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with `.update()`.

```
myLineChart.data.datasets[0].pointRadius = 5;
myLineChart.update()
```

[Refer to documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible
You have to merge the new field into your data object

You can achieve this by doing :

```
// first chart
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(mycanvas,{
  data:data
})
// second chart
var newData = data;
newData.datasets[0].pointRadius = 5;
var myLineChart2 = Chart.line(mycanvas2,{
  data:newData
})
```